# building a JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I have a two part question (Very new to JSON)

1. I need to build a json object out of attr 'data-id'.  Can a JSON object be a single 'array' of numbers?
2. I have got the code for this but I am struggling to build the JSON object, as follows:

code:

```
var displayed = {};
$('table#livefeed tr').each(function (i) {
    var peopleID = $(this).attr("data-id");
    //console.log("id: " + peopleID);
    if(peopleID!="undefined") displayed += peopleID;
});
console.log(displayed);
```

However this does not work properly, I just end up with string of objects added together.

Comment: The `+` operator is for strings(generally). Your `displayed` in an object literal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A JSON object can be an array of numbers.

Try something like this:

```
var displayed = [];
$('table#livefeed tr').each(function (i) {
    var peopleID = $(this).attr("data-id");
    if(peopleID!="undefined") 
        displayed.push(peopleID);
});
console.log(displayed);
```

To turn it into JSON,

```
JSON.stringify(displayed);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you build and object then you use `JSON.stringify(object);` to create the string. But you also have an error. If you are checking `peopleID` to be defined you need to use `typeof` as an undefined attribute won't be the string 'undefined':

```
var displayed = [];
$('table#livefeed tr').each(function (i) {
    var peopleID = $(this).attr("data-id");
    //console.log("id: " + peopleID);
    if(typeof(peopleID)!="undefined") displayed.push(peopleID);
});
console.log(displayed);
var jsonDisplay = JSON.stringify(displayed);
console.log("JSON: " + jsonDisplay);
```